# Why do I need to await for a coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am starting with websockets and `asyncio` and have a hard time understanding the logic behind. I used threading on Python in the past as well as AJAX calls on Javascript (so I have an idea of the concept of multiple threads (I/O bound) and calls to procedures which results are acted upon asynchronously).

The example server is below. My aim is to provide a websocket connection and two functions which will be called every 10 seconds, without waiting for the results (so exactly one call every 10 seconds, no matter how long it takes for the functions to process).

```
import time
import arrow
import websockets
import asyncio

async def time1(websocket):
    # simulation of a time intensive operation
    time.sleep(2)
    msg = '1 ' + arrow.now()
    print(msg)
    websocket.send(msg)

async def time2(websocket):
    # simulation of a time intensive operation
    time.sleep(3)
    msg = '2 ' + arrow.now()
    print(msg)
    websocket.send(msg)

async def update_info(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = arrow.now()
        if not now.second % 10:
            time1(websocket)
        if not now.second % 10:
            time2(websocket)

        time.sleep(1)

start_server = websockets.serve(update_info, 'localhost', 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I expected to get, once the client connected, on the next full 10 seconds, the functions fired. They would complete after 2 and 3 seconds, then be fired on the next full 10 seconds etc.

What I got instead was

```
D:/Dropbox/dev/domotique/webserver.py:708: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'time1' was never awaited
  time1(websocket)
D:/Dropbox/dev/domotique/webserver.py:710: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'time2' was never awaited
  time2(websocket)
```

and none of the messages were either sent or printed.

Why do I have to `await` for the coroutines? I would like to fire them up form `update_info` and forget about them (= leave them to their processing and let them send the data via the websocket). **What is wrong with my approach?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await` effectively couples the awaited coroutine to the event loop, waits for it to finish, then continues. If you don't `await` the coroutine, then this won't happen.

If you just want to run a coroutine in the background (more like a `Task`) then use `asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine())`, which will spin-off a `Task` and let you continue-on with other items.

EDIT: A gotcha for newcomers to async is that if you have multiple running tasks, then unless the tasks have internal `await` statements the event loop will get stuck with that task unless it returns. The way an event loop gives the impression of doing two things at once is by juggling back-and-forth between different bits of code. The `await` statements are the points between which the event loop can do the juggling. So when one piece of code is awaiting, another piece of code gets the go-ahead to run. Once that other piece of code hits an `await`, then the next piece of code in the line-up gets the go-ahead, etc. In other words, be mindful of where you place your `awaits`, and design your code in such a way that long running bits of code don't block the more dynamic components that benefit from async.